# vertical sliding accordion not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress theme [here](http://ostadabedini.com/) and I use a jquery [vertical sliding accordion](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/22/vertical-sliding-accordion/) plugin inside. I tried to use the plugin like did in the demo:

```
<div class="row zj-motoon-container">
  <div id="va-accordion" class=" va-container">

    <div class="va-nav">
      <span class="va-nav-prev">Previous</span>
      <span class="va-nav-next">Next</span>
    </div>


    <div class="zjcontainer">
      <div class=" row va-slice va-slice-1 va-slice-color-1">

      <div class="col-md-pull-3 ">
        <h3 class="va-title"> آخرین جلسات درس </h3>
      </div>

        <div class=" col-md-push-9  va-content">
          <p> جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای  </p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="row va-slice va-slice-2 va-slice-color-2">
      <div class="col-sm-pull-3">
        <h3 class="va-title"> آخرین سخنرانی ها </h3>
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-push-9 va-content">
          <p>Keith Johnson</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row va-slice va-slice-3 va-slice-color-3">
      <div class="col-sm-pull-3">
        <h3 class="va-title"> آخرین پرسش و پاسخ ها </h3>
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-push-9 va-content">
          <p>Andrew Alaniz</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row va-slice va-slice-4 va-slice-color-4">
      <div class="col-sm-pull-3">
        <h3 class="va-title">جدیدترین مطالب</h3>
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-push-9 va-content">
          <p>Ben Freeman</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row va-slice va-slice-5 va-slice-color-5">
      <div class="col-sm-pull-3">
        <h3 class="va-title">پربازدیدترین مطالب</h3>
      </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-push-9 va-content">
          <p>Alex Schuman</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row va-slice va-slice-6 va-slice-color-6">
      <div class="col-sm-pull-3">
        <h3 class="va-title">جدیدترین تولیدات رسانه ای</h3>
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-push-9 va-content">
          <p>Maria Wales</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row va-slice va-slice-7 va-slice-color-7">
      <div class="col-sm-pull-3">
        <h3 class="va-title">جدیدترین تولیدات مکتوب</h3>
      </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-push-9 va-content"><p>Paul White</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row va-slice va-slice-8 va-slice-color-8">
      <div class="col-sm-pull-3">
        <h3 class="va-title">جدیدترین نظرات کاربران</h3>
      </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-push-9 va-content">
          <p>Paul White</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also added included files to "functions.php" file of the theme and added this code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#va-accordion').vaccordion({
      accordionW : 76.5,
      accordionH :750,
      visibleSlices : 8,
      expandedHeight  : 1,
      animOpacity   : 0.1,
      contentAnimSpeed: 100
    });
```

});

to "custom-scripts.js" and included this file too. Now I have two problems with that.

1) It works good in Mozilla but when I open my site on chrome it is not sliding up. when you click on a slide and scroll down everything is OK but when you scroll up it continue sliding bottom.

2) when mouse cursor goes on the accordion it stops scrolling page. I tried to remove one of the required files named "scrollMonitor.js" which I thought makes plugin scroll like this but nothing changed and plugin was still working like the same way.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Please review [ask]. Show us some relevant code and don't expect people to click off to a site they aren't sure they can trust.

Comment: Thank you!

I am new here and I have to notice these. I tried to update mu question. I really don't know if I have asked my question good or not!